# How to Stop a Service after some execution and start the new activity?

Tags: android, service, android-intent

> I want to stop my service went it complete its tasks. but service wont be stopped I override the onDestroy() but it dose not work. When service stops it will start a new activity.
> below is my code

**DataService.java**

```
  package com.remote.synchronizer.haris;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DataService extends Service {

    boolean wifi,edge;
    private Timer timer= new Timer();
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String un,shop,city,date,order;
    private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){

        super.onCreate();
        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    //  this.stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.e("Service Started", "Successful");
                while(true){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //Checking network connectivity
                                wifi=NetworkInfo.Wifi(DataService.this);
                                edge=NetworkInfo.EDGE(DataService.this);

                                if(wifi==true||edge==true)
                                {
                                    int count=mySQLiteAdapter.getCCount();
                                    int counter=0;

                                    if(mySQLiteAdapter.getCCount()>0){

                                        while(counter<count){
                                            Log.e("Service Network", "Network is online");

                                            int id=mySQLiteAdapter.getID();

                                            List<NameValuePair> contacts=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                                            contacts=mySQLiteAdapter.getSingleRecord(id);

                                            String url="http://10.0.2.2:3325/Product/Create?"; 

                                            int response = 0;
                                            try 
                                            {   
                                                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(url, contacts);

                                                if(response==200){
                                                    mySQLiteAdapter.delete_byID(id);
                                                    Log.e("Data Sent", "Response 200");
                                                    counter++;
                                                }

                                                else{

                                                    Log.e("Service Data", "Faield to upload data" );
                                                }

                                            }
                                            catch (Exception e)
                                            {
                                                Log.e("Data Sending Error", e.toString());
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    //
                                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Log.e("Service Network", "Network is offline");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e("Data Sending Error", e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.v("SERVICE","Service killed");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //timer.cancel();
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
        callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        callIntent.setClass(this, com.remote.synchronizer.haris.Login.class);
        startActivity(callIntent);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

> somewhere i have read that don`t stop the service Android will stop itself. If it is like that then kindly edit my code and tell how can i start a new activity when my work finish. Do i need to stop the timer? Then the onStartCommand will stop and it will call the onDestroy? if yes then how can i stop the timer because i have tried but no success.

Comment: I think you should interrupt your thread can catch InterruptException

Comment: otherwise your thread will keep running, you need to stop (interrupt) your thread.

Comment: `onDestroy()` in your service will only be called by Android **after** it has stopped.

Comment: @Algo the thread user started in `onStartCommand()` is complete after it calls `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` (ie: pretty much immediately after it starts. The `Timer` has a thread that it uses to schedule the `TimerTask` on. This will need to be cancelled when it is no longer needed.

Comment: i have updated the above class in which now i used Thread.sleep() and try to interrupt the thread but it wont stop. when i used this.stopSelf() in onCreate method it destroy the service but thread still run in background. Now how i stop the thread after my work done?

Comment: better use IntentService it will handle those things automatically

Comment: I gave a try to IntentService but its stops my execution means service stops. Thats the reason i used Service.

Answer (score 1):

- if you need a service to stop itself after it completed,you shoud use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)
- onDestory() is used to release your resource,it will be called when the service is no longer used.
- start activity like this:

  ```
  final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
      public void HandleMessage(Message msg) {
          if(msg.what == START_NEW_ACTIVITY) {
              Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
              callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
              callIntent.setClass(this, com.remote.synchronizer.haris.Login.class);
              startActivity(callIntent);
          }
      }
  };
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      new Thread() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              // do your job here
              mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(START_NEW_ACTIVITY);
         }
      }.start();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the service after your work has been finished simply call `stopSelf()` or `stopSelf(startId)`.

If you want to start the activity after the service has been finished, Before calling the `stopSelf()` or `stopSelf(startId)`, you should create the intent of the activity and set the flag `mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`.
and start your activity by calling `startActivity(intent)`